# c# get content from url like facebook and linkedin does

Tags: c#, web-scraping

How can I achieve the same functionality (in C#) like Facebook and Linkedin does when posting a url into your status?

As you can see below from Linkedin, you enter an URL and Linkedin automatically fetches the title, image and the content of that article truncated.

[image]

Comment: Not knowing the details of this implementation, my guess would be https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed/. Or the appropriate public API for the platform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net) to parse the HTML. It's available as a NuGet package.

If you have a WebPage class defined like this:

```
public class WebPage
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string PageUrl { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

You can use the following code for parsing the HTML:

```
public WebPage ParseHtml(string html, Uri uri)
{
    var document = new HtmlDocument();
    document.LoadHtml(html);

    // remove scripts
    foreach (var script in document.DocumentNode.Descendants("script").ToArray())
    {
        script.Remove();
    }

    // remove styles
    foreach (var style in document.DocumentNode.Descendants("style").ToArray())
    {
        style.Remove();
    }

    // remove comments
    foreach (var style in document.DocumentNode.Descendants("#comment").ToArray())
    {
        style.Remove();
    }

    // sometimes </form> is not removed so we have to remove it manually
    string innerText = (document.DocumentNode.InnerText ?? "").Trim().Replace("</form>", "");

    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var lines = innerText.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine, "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        string trimmed = StringUtils.DecodeAndRemoveSpaces(line);
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(trimmed))
        {
            sb.AppendLine(trimmed);
        }
    }

    var webPage = new WebPage { PageUrl = uri.AbsoluteUri };

    var titleNode = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("title").SingleOrDefault();
    if (titleNode != null)
    {
        webPage.Title = StringUtils.DecodeAndRemoveSpaces(titleNode.InnerText ?? "");
    }

    webPage.Text = sb.ToString();

    return webPage;
}
```

And the utils class:

```
public class StringUtils
{
    public static string DecodeAndRemoveSpaces(string text)
    {
        var trimed = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(text.Trim());
        trimed = trimed.Replace("\t", " ");
        // replace double spaces
        trimed = Regex.Replace(trimed, @"[ ]{2,}", " ");

        return trimed;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public async Task Test()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var uri = new Uri("http://www.google.com");
        string html = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);

        var webPage = ParseHtml(html, uri);
    }
}
```

Comment: Am I missing something or this will parse the content from a local html file? What about url?

Comment: You need to get the HTML first. You can use HttpClient.GetStringAsync http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.getstringasync(v=vs.118).aspx

And then you send this HTML and Uri to `ParseHtml` method

Answer (score 1):

You can send a get request to that URL. Then you can fetch the title, images and content.

You can a see general example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9(v=vs.110).aspx/) (scroll down to "Example").